# Configure keyboard shortcut to switch tabs with alt + number in jetbrains IDES (PhpStorm)

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts, jetbrains-ide, key-bindings

I want to use the keyboard shortcut: `Alt + number` to switch tabs in the JetBrains suites (PyCharm, PhpStorm, etc). For now I do it with the shortcut: `Ctrl + Alt + arrow right/left`.

I know it is not very related to the forum but it is a very useful tool for programming and if you would provide me with that it would be great.

Comment: **1)** `Alt+Number` is used to activate various tool windows (e.g. Project View, Structure, VCS etc). You would need to remove those shortcuts first. **2)** Active specific editor window: such actions do exist, you would just need to assign shortcuts to them, check this comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68324#focus=Comments-27-3176164.0-0 **3)** For tabs moving, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23721 (it has a link to such plugin, mentioned right there at the top)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but found a solution. It's possible to set it up manually in the editor settings. Go to the following preferences section:

```
Keymap -> Other -> Tabs
```

From here you can add a keyboard shortcut per tab, so for example "Select Tab #1" should be <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> for Windows and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> for macOS. I hope it helps